# The name of the following theorem: Decompositon of Kn into arbitary cycles

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

As far as I'm concerned the following theorem was proven about ten years ago:

> Let $n$ be an odd number and $c_1, c_2, ..., c_k$ be integers so that $c_i > 2$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{k} c_i = {n \choose 2}$. Then $K_n$ can be decomposed into   $C_{c_1}, C_{c_2}, ..., C_{c_k}$.

I had been looking for the name of the upper theorem, whereas I couldn't find any results. What is the name of this theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the [Alspach's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alspach%27s_conjecture).
Darryn Bryant, Daniel Horsley and William Pettersson claimed a solution in 2014:

*Bryant, Darryn; Horsley, Daniel; Pettersson, William*, [**Cycle decompositions. V: Complete graphs into cycles of arbitrary lengths**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/pdt051), Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. (3) 108, No. 5, 1153-1192 (2014). [ZBL1296.05044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1296.05044).